# How to distinguish between lists and values?

Tags: programming, list-manipulation, numerical-integration

I have a (hopefully small) problem with some numerical integration algorithm, more specifically I want to integrate the imaginary part of a complex valued function, e.g. `f[u_]:=Exp[-iuK]` with $K\in\mathbb{R}$. As mentioned I am only interested in `Im[f]`, in the example `-Sin[u K]`.

Now if I integrate with Mathematica

```
NIntegrate[f, {s, Min[roots[[ 1 ]], roots[[ 2 ]]],
                Max[roots[[ 1 ]], roots[[ 2 ]]]}, AccuracyGoal->aGoal, 
                PrecisionGoal->pGoal, WorkingPrecision->wPrecision ];
```

I get two different results depending on `f`:

1. if I use `-Sin[u K]`, it returns `somenumber`
2. if I use `Im[f]`, it returns a list `{ somenumber }`
   Those two have to be treated differently and that crashes my program. I have a few questions:

Why does Mathematica sometimes return lists, and sometimes values?
How can I distinguish between a list and a value, i.e.

```
If xyz is a list then 
  do something 
else 
  do something else
end
```

Any other ideas how one could avoid these different return "types"? The manual and anything I found hasn't been useful so far.

Comment: I'm trying to understand why `NIntegrate` is returning a `List` in one case, and a simple value in another. So, what are you using for `roots`?

Comment: I cannot reproduce this behavior. *E.g.*, `Clear[f];
f[u_] := Exp[-I u];
NIntegrate[Im[f[s]], {s, 0, 1}]` works just fine (returning a Real value).

Comment: NIntegrate will return a list when its argument is a list. Therefore I suggest you investigate under what circumstances your f is a list. With your example code, one way this could happen is if K is sometimes a list.

Comment: The simple example I gave doesn't reproduce the error, that's true.  Probably some input arguments of NIntegrate cause the behavior, however, I'll use one of the answers below. Thank you all!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

How about putting the results in a list and then removing unneeded braces.?

```
a = 76.5
b = {4, 5, 12.3}
Flatten[{a}]
Flatten[{b}]
```

[image: lists]

That way you are always dealing with a list of values.

---

Or simply place braces around numbers (that are not already in a list):

```
If[NumericQ[x], x = {x}]
```

Answer (score 17):

Generally speaking, you can recognize a list because it'll have `List` as its `Head`. For example:

```
Head[{1,2,3}]
```

will return `List`.

For your example conditional where you want to change what you do based on the `Head` of the resulting expression, you can use `Switch`, such as in:

```
Switch[result,
       _List, what you want to do with a list,
       _, what you want to do otherwise]
```

A pattern of the form `_List` means "only match expressions with the head `List`. The next pattern, `_`, means "match an expression with any head". Mathematica stops in a `Switch` at the first match, so `List` will be preferred over "anything else".

Comment: I need to remember that syntax. I keep using Head[result]===List.... yours is much nicer.

Answer (score 11):

It is useful to write functions that can handle expressions in several different forms.

Here is a function that will return `1` plus a numeric argument, or `1` plus the first element of a list, if it is given a list.

```
f[n_?NumericQ] := n + 1
f[{n_?NumericQ, ___}] := n + 1
```

This can also be written in one line using `Alternatives`:

```
f[n_?NumericQ | {n_?NumericQ, ___}] := n + 1
```

When using `Alternatives` the possibilities will be checked in the explicit order you give.
When using separate lines *Mathematica* attempts to intelligently order the rules by specificity.

Usage:

```
f[Pi]
```

> ```
> 1 + Pi
> ```

```
f[{1, 2, 3}]
```

> ```
> 2
> ```

```
f["bird"]
```

> ```
> f["bird"]
> ```

You can use the same syntax for `Replace` rules if you do not want to create a function.

```
Pi /. n_?NumericQ | {n_?NumericQ, ___} :> n + 1

{1, 2, 3} /. n_?NumericQ | {n_?NumericQ, ___} :> n + 1
```

> ```
> 1 + Pi
>
> 2
> ```

Comment: You had my +1 with mentioning `Alternatives`, I can't upvote you any further.

Answer (score 7):

Some functions are intermittent about whether they wrap their results in a list.  I'm not sure about `NIntegrate`, but `Reap` (for example) certainly does.  For purposes of discussion, let's define such a function:

```
g[x_] /; OddQ[x] := {10 x}
g[x_] := -x

g[1]
```

> {10}

```
g[2]
```

> -2

We can define `h` to automatically "unwrap" resulting lists like this:

```
h[x_] := g[x] /. {n_} :> n

h[1]
```

> 10

```
h[2]
```

> -2

```
Table[h[x], {x, 0, 10}]
```

> {0, 10, -2, 30, -4, 50, -6, 70, -8, 90, -10}

Also, `ListQ` can be used to distinguish lists from other value types:

```
ListQ[1]
```

> False

```
ListQ[{1}]
```

> True

Answer (score 2):

Alright, I figured out my mistake - as Mathematica distinguishes between different bracket types, one shouldn't confuse () and {}, as I did in a part of my calculations. Sorry for the puzzlement.