# Alternatives pattern in a function definition

Tags: function-construction

I thought that I remembered a way to write a function definition using "|", but can't find documentation for it.  So for example, I'd want to define:

```
f[1, x_] := x^2;
f[2, x_] := x*12;
```

I thought there was a syntax, kind of like a "select case" or "switch" statement that used "|".  Is there?

Comment: Are you thinking of `Condition`? (look it up in the docs)

Comment: In this particular case, it does not seem appropriate to use such a construct anyway, because your r.h.sides are different. But also in general, the use of `Alternatives` in the top-level function definitions is not allowed.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin Just to clarify, `f[1, x_] | f[3, x_] := x^2` is not allowed, but `f[1 | 3, x_] := x^2` is allowed.  (It's not clear to me which the OP is trying to recall, if either.)

Comment: @MichaelE2 I meant the first one, that's why I said "top-level". I agree that I could've made that more clear.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin I figured that out, but I was thinking of the second one when I read the question.  I really was trying to clarify it for the OP, just in case.

Comment: @MichaelE2 In fact, there have been a few times where I really wanted the top-level `Alternatives` to work. I don't know what was the rationale behind this limitation / design decision, but probably there was some good reason for this.

Comment: @Leonid What head with the definition be attached to in that case?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I only meant the special case where all heads of the top-level alternatives are the same. In general, I agree that this is not very well-defined.

Comment: @Leonid There's your answer I think. :-)

Comment: @LeonidShifrin Like this: `f[PatternSequence[1, x_] | PatternSequence[3, x_]] := x^2`?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard This is a general answer, for things like `f[x_]|g[x_]:=...` - this I anticipated before. But this does not explain why not to make an exception for things like `f[patt1]|f[patt2]:=...`.

Comment: @MichaelE2 I rather meant something like `f[1,x_]|f[2,x_]:=x^2`.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin  Sorry, I meant would the `PatternSequence` method suit some cases for you.   But I think we may be drifting away from the present question?

Comment: @MichaelE2 Oh I see. Well, `PatternSequence` does cover some cases, but not all. I don't remember now whether those needs I had in the past would've been satisfied with `PatternSequence`. Re: drifting - I guess so...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It sounds like you are describing [pattern guards](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2225811/211232) or [pattern-matching syntax](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/oreilly-book/html/book-ora016.html) found variously in  ML/SML/OCAML/Haskell/F#.  For example, in Haskell one could write:

```
-- This is Haskell, *not* Mathematica

f a x
    | a == 1 = x ^ 2
    | a == 2 = x * 12
```

*Mathematica* does not support this kind of syntax using a pipe symbol.  The definitions exhibited in the question are idiomatic.  We can write code that looks vaguely like the Haskell syntax using explicit pattern matching:

```
f[a_, x_] := a /.
    { 1 :> x ^ 2
    , 2 :> x * 12
    , _ :> $Failed
    }
```

This is not very idiomatic.  It could possibly be convenient for more elaborate argument list shapes and conditions.  The `$Failed` case was added to point out that we would otherwise have the (surprising?) behaviour of returning `a` unchanged if it is not `1` or `2`.  An `Message` / `Abort` sequence might be more appropriate, depending upon the application (and mimicking Haskell's built-in behaviour).

Other answers to this question show how one can avoid repeating argument lists across function definitions using features such as `Switch` or `Alternatives`.

Answer (score 14):

You may be remembering a way that I sometimes write function definitions or replacement rules using what I call vanishing patterns, using [`Alternatives`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Alternatives.html) (short form `|`).  Some examples:

- [Simple power counting](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8544384/618728)
- [Function argument to default under certain condition](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/19488/function-argument-to-default-under-certain-condition/19933#19933)
- [How to get Cases to wrap results in an arbitrary head?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/31754/how-to-get-cases-to-wrap-results-in-an-arbitrary-head/31755#31755)
- [Generalization to AllTrue, AnyTrue and NoneTrue](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/71698/generalization-to-alltrue-anytrue-and-nonetrue/71700#71700)

This technique can considerably condense some code, but at the expense of clarity for those not familiar with it, and often a slight decrease in performance.  I do not see any (simple) way to apply it to the example in the question, and shoehorning the method into code where it does not naturally fit (for one accustomed to it) surely hurts clarity and should be avoided outside of "code golf" games.

To provide a simple example of the method where I believe it does fit consider:

```
f[a_Real, x_] := x*a
f[b_Integer, x_] := x^b
```

This could instead be written:

```
f[a_Real | b_Integer, x_] := (x*a)^b
```

Whichever pattern (`a_Real` or `b_Integer`) does not match is left out of the right-hand-side, and because of the single-argument behavior of `Times` and `Power` this is handled correctly.

Another place the method works very well is inserting elements into an expression at specific places based on pattern.  For example, suppose you want an function than takes a list and an integer, and appends the integer if it is odd and "prepends" the integer if it is even.  This can be written cleanly as:

```
 g[{x___}, e_?EvenQ | o_?OddQ] := {e, x, o}
```

Test:

```
Fold[g, {}, Range@10]
```

> ```
> {10, 8, 6, 4, 2, 1, 3, 5, 7, 9}
> ```

More simply you can use `Alternatives` to match different input forms, e.g.:

- [f[arg1, arg2,...,argN] vs. f[{arg1, arg2,...,argN}]](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/15749/farg1-arg2-argn-vs-farg1-arg2-argn/15757#15757)
- [How to distinguish between lists and values?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2493/how-to-distinguish-between-lists-and-values/2507#2507)

Answer (score 6):

There is a `Switch` statement, but the syntax to do what you need is

```
f[s_,x_]:= Switch[s,
    1, x^2,
    2, x*12,
    True, "something else"
 ]
```

The third option *which I forgot in my first edit) takes care of what happens when s is neither 1 or 2.

Otherwise you could use the functional overloading approach you mentioned in your question. It works because Mathematica will order your definitions from the more specific to the more general, and after defining `f[1,x_]` and `f[2,x_]` you can add a definition for the general case `f[s_,x_]`. I like this approach better, since it can leave the result unevaluated when x is not 1 or 2.

The 'pipe' (i.e. `Alternatives`) can be used to assign values that are the same for a finite set of a certain parameter's values, like in

```
g[1 | 2, x_] := x^("1 or 2")
g[y_,x_]:=x^"something else"
```

It means that the function have the same output for alternative values of input.