# List manipulation - adding last element of sublist to each sublist

Tags: list-manipulation, replacement

If I have the following list:

```
{{}, {1, 2}, {}, {2, 4, 3}, {5, 4, 3, 2}, {}}
```

How can I add the last element of each sublist to each sublist?

The results should be (empty sublists should be filled with zeros, here I know that I can use the replacement `/.{}->{0}`):

```
{{0}, {1, 2, 2}, {0}, {2, 4, 3, 3}, {5, 4, 3, 2, 2}, {0}}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
lst = {{}, {1, 2}, {}, {2, 4, 3}, {5, 4, 3, 2}, {}} ;
Join[lst, (lst /. {} -> {0})[[All, {-1}]], 2]
```

> {{0}, {1, 2, 2}, {0}, {2, 4, 3, 3}, {5, 4, 3, 2, 2}, {0}}

Also

```
ClearAll[f]; f[{}] = {0}; f[{a___, b_}] := {a, b, b};
f /@ {{}, {1, 2}, {}, {2, 4, 3}, {5, 4, 3, 2}, {}}
```

> {{0}, {1, 2, 2}, {0}, {2, 4, 3, 3}, {5, 4, 3, 2, 2}, {0}}

**Timings:**

```
ClearAll[f0, f1, f2, f3, f4, f5];
f0[{}] = {0}; f0[{a___, b_}] := {a, b, b}; 
f1 = f0 /@ # &;
f2 = Join[#, (# /. {} -> {0})[[All, {-1}]], 2] &;
f3 = Replace[#, {{a___, last_} :> {a, last, last}, {} -> {0}}, -1] &; (*MarcoB *)
f4 = Replace[#, {a___, b_} | {} :> {a, b, b + 0}, {1}] &; (* Mr.Wizard *)
f5 = # /. {{} -> {0}, _ :> # ~ Join~{#[[-1]]}} & /@ # &; (* Fraccalo *)
f6 = Append[#, If[# == {}, 0, #[[-1]]]] & /@ # &; (* GIM *)

SeedRandom[1]
testlst = RandomInteger[10, #] & /@ RandomInteger[10, 1000000];
t1 = First[AbsoluteTiming[r1 = f1@testlst;]];
t2 = First[AbsoluteTiming[r2 = f2@testlst;]];
t3 = First[AbsoluteTiming[r3 = f3@testlst;]];
t4 = First[AbsoluteTiming[r4 = f4@testlst;]];
t5 = First[AbsoluteTiming[r5 = f5@testlst;]];
t6 = First[AbsoluteTiming[r6 = f6@testlst;]];
Equal[r1, r2, r3, r4, r5, r6]
```

> True

```
Grid[Prepend[SortBy[Transpose[{{"f1", "f2", "f3", "f4", "f5", "f6"},
  {t1, t2, t3, t4, t5, t6}}], Last], {"function", "timing"}], Dividers -> All]
```

[image]

Answer (score 8):

```
Replace[
  {{}, {1, 2}, {}, {2, 4, 3}, {5, 4, 3, 2}, {}}, 
  {{a___, last_} :> {a, last, last}, {} -> {0}},
  -1
]

(* Out:  {{0}, {1, 2, 2}, {0}, {2, 4, 3, 3}, {5, 4, 3, 2, 2}, {0}} *)
```

Comment: Great ... thank you

Answer (score 8):

A single-Rule method using [`Alternatives`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Alternatives.html):

```
in = {{}, {1, 2}, {}, {2, 4, 3}, {5, 4, 3, 2}, {}};

Replace[in, {a___, b_} | {} :> {a, b, b + 0}, {1}]
```

> ```
> {{0}, {1, 2, 2}, {0}, {2, 4, 3, 3}, {5, 4, 3, 2, 2}, {0}}
> ```

Some additional examples that may help in understanding this code:

- [Alternatives pattern in a function definition](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/44081/alternatives-pattern-in-a-function-definition/44084#44084)

Answer (score 6):

One line solution, just for fun:

```
# /. {{} -> {0}, _ :> #~Join~{#[[-1]]}} & /@ list
```

> {{0}, {1, 2, 2}, {0}, {2, 4, 3, 3}, {5, 4, 3, 2, 2}, {0}}

Answer (score 6):

You can also use `Append` and an `If` statement, and this is fairly quick: if the list is empty, append a 0, else append the last element in the list, and map this function across your input:

```
Append[#, If[# == {}, 0, #[[-1]]]] & /@ {{}, {1, 2}, {}, {2, 4, 3}, {5, 4, 3, 2}, {}}
```

For timing, use `AbsoluteTiming` to get:

```
AbsoluteTiming[
 Append[#, If[# == {}, 0, #[[-1]]]] & /@ {{}, {1, 2}, {}, {2, 4,3}, {5, 4, 3, 2}, {}}]
```

> {0.000024, {{0}, {1, 2, 2}, {0}, {2, 4, 3, 3}, {5, 4, 3, 2, 2}, {0}}}

Answer (score 5):

Using two-argument form of `Last`:

```
h = Map[Append[#, Last[#, 0]] &];
```

***Example:***

```
h @ {{}, {1, 2}, {}, {2, 4, 3}, {5, 4, 3, 2}, {}}
```

> ```
> {{0}, {1, 2, 2}, {0}, {2, 4, 3, 3}, {5, 4, 3, 2, 2}, {0}}
> ```

Comment: Thanks, very useful for me in in many other cases too

Answer (score 3):

**Using `SequenceReplace`:**

```
lst = {{}, {1, 2}, {}, {2, 4, 3}, {5, 4, 3, 2}, {}}
SequenceReplace[lst, {{{}} :> {0}, {{a__, b_}} :> {a, b, b}}]
```

> {{0}, {1, 2, 2}, {0}, {2, 4, 3, 3}, {5, 4, 3, 2, 2}, {0}}

Answer (score 3):

```
list = {{}, {1, 2}, {}, {2, 4, 3}, {5, 4, 3, 2}, {}};
```

**1.**

```
add[{a__, b_}] := {a, b, b}
add[{}] := {0}

add /@ list
```

{{0}, {1, 2, 2}, {0}, {2, 4, 3, 3}, {5, 4, 3, 2, 2}, {0}}

**2.**

```
ReplaceAt[list, {{} :> {0}, {a__, b_} :> {a, b, b}}, All]
```

{{0}, {1, 2, 2}, {0}, {2, 4, 3, 3}, {5, 4, 3, 2, 2}, {0}}

`ReplaceAt` was introduced with V 13.1

Answer (score 2):

Another way is to use `Cases` and `If` as follows:

```
list = {{}, {1, 2}, {}, {2, 4, 3}, {5, 4, 3, 2}, {}};

Cases[list, x_ :> If[x == {}, Append[x, 0], Append[x, Last@x]]]

(*{{0}, {1, 2, 2}, {0}, {2, 4, 3, 3}, {5, 4, 3, 2, 2}, {0}}*)
```

Or using `ReplaceList`:

```
ReplaceList[#, {{a___, b_} :> Splice@{a, b, b}, {} -> 0}] & /@ list

(*{{0}, {1, 2, 2}, {0}, {2, 4, 3, 3}, {5, 4, 3, 2, 2}, {0}}*)
```